# VB to C# conversion incongruency with lambdas

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, lambda

I have a bit of code that I have been tasked with converting to C# from VB. A snippet of mine seems like it cannot be converted from one to the other, and if so, I just don't know how to do it and am getting a little frustrated.

Here's some background:

`OrderForm` is an `abstract` class, inherited by `Invoice` (and also `PurchaseOrder`). The following VB snippet works correctly:

```
Dim Invs As List(Of OrderForm) = GetForms(theOrder.OrderID)
....
Dim inv As Invoice = Invs.Find(
    Function(someInv As Invoice) thePO.SubPONumber = someInv.SubInvoiceNumber)
```

In C#, the best I came to converting this is:

```
List<OrderForm> Invs = GetForms(theOrder.OrderID);
....
Invoice inv = Invs.Find(
    (Invoice someInv) => thePO.SubPONumber == someInv.SubInvoiceNumber);
```

However, I get the following error when I do this:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Predicate' because the parameter types do not match the delegate parameter types

Is there any way to fix this without restructuring my whole codebase?

Comment: Almost all C# can be converted to VB.NET and vice versa because it all compiles to MSIL. You just need to find the sweet spot to express the issue. This is just a clarification comment.

Comment: For converting VB to C# - have you considered disassembling the compiled VB function in [Redgate .NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) (Free version works fine), and setting the output type to C#?  May help for these tricksy types of conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that `OrderForm` derives from `Invoice`. If so, rewrite your lambda to omit the explicit type declaration inside the `Find`. (Can't say with certainty for VB, but for C#, the type is not required in a lambda, it will be inferred.)

```
Invoice inv = Invs.Find(someInv => thePO.SubPONumber == someInv.SubInvoiceNumber);
```

**Edit**

Based on your comment, you're going to have to do some casting inside the lambda and also to the result.

```
Invoice inv = (Invoice)Invs.Find(someInv => 
                   thePO.SubPONumber == ((Invoice)someInv).SubInvoiceNumber);
```

Or you could elect to use LINQ extension methods as opposed to `Find` in `List<>`

```
Invoice inv = Invs.OfType<Invoice>().FirstOrDefault<Invoice>(someInv => someInv.SubInvoiceNumber == thePO.SubPONumber);
```

Comment: `Invoice` derives from `OrderForm`. That kind of works, except that the value being compared (`SubInvoiceNumber`) is specific to `Invoice` so the omission of the explicit type doesn't work :(

Comment: This is correct if you update `FirstOrDefault()` to be `FirstOrDefault<Invoice>`.

Comment: @Jason, did you really need to use `<Invoice>` in the `FirstOrDefault` call? You shouldn't need to, as `OfType` will result in an `IEnumerable<Invoice>`, so `FirstOrDefault` shouldn't need a type argument. It's unexpected if you need to be explicit.

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you convert VB to C#, **ALWAYS TURN OPTION STRICT ON**. In this case you'll see the error message before you even hit c#. In this case VB will return

> Option Strict On does not allow
>   narrowing in implicit type conversions
>   between the lambda expression and
>   delegate 'System.Predicate(Of
>   OrderForm)'

From there you can pretty easily see that you're trying to implicitly cast a base class as a child class. The C# code that people wrote here is correct, here's the VB equivalent:

```
Dim inv As Invoice = DirectCast(Invs.Find(Function(someInv As OrderForm) SubPONumber = DirectCast(thePO.SubPONumber, Invoice).SubInvoiceNumber), Invoice)
```

**UPDATE**

Here's the C# version from @Anthony Pegram's post:

```
Invoice inv = (Invoice)Invs.Find(someInv => thePO.SubPONumber == ((Invoice)someInv).SubInvoiceNumber);
```

Also, I recommend that you make some changes to your pattern if possible. `GetForms()` right now returns `OrderForms` but later you just assume that they're all `Invoices`. Hopefully you've got some logic to verify that. I'd recommend that `GetForms()` actually returns `Invoices` otherwise.

Comment: +1 Took the liberty of correcting a typo in your answer: you wrote "option explicit" in one place. My recommendation would be "ALWAYS TURN OPTION STRICT ON" even if you're programming VB and not trying to convert to C# !

Comment: Thanks @MarkJ, I'm fighting a cold and my brain is a little frozen

Comment: thank you for this, but this does not answer the question. What would the C# code be?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that @Anthony Pegram had what should be the correct version. I'll update above.

Answer (score 3):

Well, `Find` is expecting a `Predicate<OrderForm>` but you are trying to give it a `Predicate<Invoice>`. It is correct that this should not compile. I'm surprised the VB.NET works.

What is `thePO`?

Additionally, the result of `Find` is an `OrderForm` and you are assigning to a variable of type `Invoice`.

Ideally, you want something like this:

```
OrderForm orderForm = Invs.Find(o => o.SomeOrderFormProperty == someValue);
```

If you want to pull invoices, you could do something like this:

```
Invoice invoice = Invs.OfType<Invoice>()
                      .SingleOrDefault(x => x.SomeInvoiceProperty == someValue);

if(invoice != null) {
    // do something
}
```

But really, if you are after `Invoice`s, why are you typing the list as `List<OrderForm>` instead of `List<Invoice>`?

Comment: I understand what the problem is... just why does it work in VB.NET and not C#, and how can I make it work in C#? Also, I need to compare `Invoice` s, so I'm not looking to pull an `OrderForm`

Comment: VB (and BASIC in general) has historically been a "do what I meant, not what I said" type of language.  So this might be a case where the compiler is inserting casts for you and changing crap around to make your life easier.  Without seeing all of the code though, it's hard to say.

Comment: what else would you like to see? i will show you whatever you want to make it more clear to you.

Comment: @Jason - I mean the OP - [mind if I call you "Bruce" to keep it clear](http://orangecow.org/pythonet/sketches/bruces.htm)? It's working in VB because you have `Option Strict Off`. It's best practise to always have `Option Strict On`, then the VB.Net compiler will warn you where casts and conversions are needed. That's what cdhowie is hinting at. See also [Chris's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611235/vb-to-c-conversion-incongruency-with-lambdas/4611736#4611736)

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Actually, you don't need to create a new list

```
List<OrderForm> Invs = new List<OrderForm> { new Invoice(1), new Invoice(2) };  
List<Invoice> invoices = Invs.OfType<Invoice>().Where(invoice => invoice.val == 1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to cast your `OrderForm` to an `Invoice`:

```
Invoice inv = (Invoice)Invs.Find(
    someInv => thePO.SubPONumber == ((Invoice)someInv).SubInvoiceNumber);
```